# Will a wet quilt with cotton wadding be bullet proof?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, everyday-life

I remember that I've been told (or saw in a movie) that a thick quilt will be much more bullet proof if it is wet. It seems to make some sense to me, but I don't know how true it is and if there have been some experiments done to verify this.

Maybe the question should go like this, compared with a dry quilt, about how many times does a totally wet quilt more bullet proof than a dry one. If we want to make it bullet proof, how thick will the quilt probably be?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to be giving you a grim answer, but one method of suppression of noise and gore is to put a pillow over the victims head before shooting them. My source(s) for this horror tale are:

1. Having two brothers in law who are policemen,
2. A niece who is studying forensic science (blame CSI type TV for the popularity of this subject).
3. A crime writer, (James Lee Burke), noted for his in depth research.

I suggest that you compare how the [**Kevlar Fibres**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulletproof_vest) in a bulletproof vest absorb the impact, compared to wet cotton, duck down, or polyester fibres, cotained within a quilt.

Kevlar fibres are so tightly woven, compared to loose fibres in a pillow, that they turn a pointed projectile into a mushroom shaped flattened shape, spreading the energy of the bullet.

Source: [Wikipedia Bullet Proof Vests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulletproof_vest)

> Ballistic vests use layers of very strong fibers to "catch" and deform a bullet, mushrooming it into a dish shape, and spreading its force over a larger portion of the vest fiber. The vest absorbs the energy from the deforming bullet, bringing it to a stop before it can completely penetrate the textile matrix. Some layers may be penetrated but as the bullet deforms, the energy is absorbed by a larger and larger fiber area.
>
> While a vest can prevent bullet penetration, the vest and wearer still absorb the bullet's energy. Even without penetration, modern pistol bullets contain enough energy to cause blunt force trauma under the impact point. Vest specifications will typically include both penetration resistance requirements and limits on the amount of impact energy that is delivered to the body.

As far as evidence goes, the TV show [Mythbusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythBusters) performed  an experiment to verify if a normal sized phone book was capable of stopping a 9mm round. It was capable of doing so, according to their results.

So if two pages of a phone book have the same stopping power as a t-shirt, then you would require  over 1,000 t-shirts, which is around 180 cm in depth.